# Pandoc Lua filter to replace specific English words to Chinese words in citations

Tags: lua, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

When writing a Chinese paper, both Chinese and English papers could be cited. However, styles are slightly differently. The example is as follows:

```
Cite an English article (Smith et al. 2022), and cite a Chinese article (张三 等 2018).
```

In other words, for papers with multiple authors, `et al.` is used for English papers, while `等` is applied for Chinese papers. Considering that [Citation Style Language](https://citationstyles.org/) cannot handle multiple languages, I’d ask help for Lua filter.

A Markdown file named `test.md` as an example:

```markdown
Cite an English article [@makarchev2022], and cite a Chinese article [@luohongyun2018].
```

Then run the command below:

```bash
pandoc -C -t native test.md
```

And the output of the main body:

```
[ Para
    [ Str "Cite"
    , Space
    , Str "an"
    , Space
    , Str "English"
    , Space
    , Str "article"
    , Space
    , Cite
        [ Citation
            { citationId = "makarchev2022"
            , citationPrefix = []
            , citationSuffix = []
            , citationMode = NormalCitation
            , citationNoteNum = 1
            , citationHash = 0
            }
        ]
        [ Str "(Makarchev"
        , Space
        , Str "et"
        , Space
        , Str "al."
        , Space
        , Str "2022)"
        ]
    , Str ","
    , Space
    , Str "and"
    , Space
    , Str "cite"
    , Space
    , Str "a"
    , Space
    , Str "Chinese"
    , Space
    , Str "article"
    , Space
    , Cite
        [ Citation
            { citationId = "luohongyun2018"
            , citationPrefix = []
            , citationSuffix = []
            , citationMode = NormalCitation
            , citationNoteNum = 2
            , citationHash = 0
            }
        ]
        [ Str "(\32599\32418\20113"
        , Space
        , Str "et"
        , Space
        , Str "al."
        , Space
        , Str "2018)"
        ]
    , Str "."
    ]
```

Because `@luohongyun2018` is a Chinese bibliography, I want to replace the last English `et al.` followed it, i.e.:

```
, Str "et"
, Space
, Str "al."
```

to an Chinese word `等`:

```
, Str "\31561"
```

Is it possible to make it via Lua filter? Following the example in the [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) page, I have tried but didn’t make it by myself.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter below does two things: it checks if the citation text contains Chinese characters and, if so, then continues to to replace the `et al.`.

The test for Chinese characters is a bit fragile; it could be made more robust by using the `utf8.codepoint` function from standard Lua library instead.

```lua
function Cite (cite)
  return cite:walk{
    Inlines = function (inlines)
      local has_cjk = false
      inlines:walk {
        Str = function (s)
          has_cjk = has_cjk or
            pandoc.layout.real_length(s.text) > pandoc.text.len(s.text)
        end
      }
      -- do nothing if this does not contain wide chars.
      if not has_cjk then
        return nil
      end

      local i = 1
      local result = pandoc.Inlines{}
      while i <= #inlines do
        if i + 2 <= #inlines and
          inlines[i].text == 'et' and
          inlines[i+1].t == 'Space' and
          inlines[i+2].text == 'al.' then
          result:insert(pandoc.Str '等')
          i = i + 3
        else
          result:insert(inlines[i])
          i = i + 1
        end
      end
      return result
    end
  }
end
```

Comment: Huge thanks! I’ve tried and it worked. For distinguishing Chinese and English citations, I found that the `Str` before `et al.` is tricky. For the English citation, it’s the original ASCII characters, generally the first author’s last name like `Makarchev`. While for the Chinese citation, the `Str` before `et al.` is the character represented with unicode ID like `\32599\32418\20113`. Could it be a potential way to detect the language?

Comment: The page of Pandoc Lua filters has a [function](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#pandoc.layout.real_length) called `real_length (str)`, which returns the real length of a string in a monospace font: 0 for a combining character, 1 for a regular character, 2 for an East Asian wide character. How could it be used here?

Comment: It worked! However, if `--metadata link-citations=true` was set for docx output, it failed to make it.

Comment: And it seemed not to work when the custom CSL was applied. But for the default `chicago-author-date style`, it worked as expected.

Comment: The `link-citations` issue is fixable by letting the filter "walk" `cite.content` to replace the `et al.`. I'll try to do that later. Not sure about the custom CSL, can you post more info? (Perhaps this should go into a new question.)

Comment: For example, if [APA style](https://www.zotero.org/styles/apa) was applied: `--csl=apa.csl`, this Lua filter didn’t work for the docx output. If the CSL file was removed, it worked well.

Comment: Could you please help to fix the issue when `link-citations` is enabled and the custom CSL is applied? Thanks!